# Should I track session_analytics.tap?

Tags: android, google-fabric

I've noticed the `session_analytics.tap` file being added to my app module every time to my project with Fabric in it.

There's no documentation as to what to do with it. ***Should I check it in to version control or not?***

Build environment:

- Android Studio 2.3.3
- Fabric Gradle plugin 1.+ (1.24.2 exactly)
- Crashlytics Android Library 2.6.7@aar

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. I think that's unrelated to Fabric. I did some testing and don't see it added on a sample project.

Comment: Thanks! Apologies for the mixup. Not sure where the files are from then.

Comment: Hmm, actually it seems to be part of the Fabric Answers. Could it be part of the Android Studio plugin or something?

Comment: See here for example. It is on a device as opposed to the source folder, but I'm getting autogenerated session_analytics_to_send files too https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/internal-storage-left-flashing-rom-t3166281

Comment: Thanks! Does this only happen after a build an run?

Comment: I think it's related to running unit tests with Robolectric. Have you seen this before?

Comment: And how can I make a git repro with a sample application? With `cannonball-android`?